# Yii Dropdown list options with html options

Tags: php, forms, yii

Im new to Yii and i cant get my head around all these arrays. I successfully added a new dropdown list which works great:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,'user_id', CHtml::listData(
        User::model()->findAll(
            array('order' => 'user_fname ASC')
        ), 
        'user_id', 'user_fname'
     )
 ); 
 ?>
```

But all my other inputs are styled like this:

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldGroup(
    $model,'date',array(
        'widgetOptions'=>array(
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'class'=>'span5'
             )
          )
      )
 ); 
 ?>
```

I tried this and a load of other different variations but none are working, how do i apply the class in this scenario?

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
    $model,'user_id', CHtml::listData(
        User::model()->findAll(
            array(
                'order' => 'user_fname ASC'
             )
        ), 
        'user_id', 'user_fname'
     ),
     array('htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'span5'))
 ); 
 ?>
```

I also want to add this but ill settle for getting the class working first and then ill try and figure that out

```
array('empty'=>'Select a name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the class on an outer container, like this:

```
<div class="span5">
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
$model,'user_id', CHtml::listData(
    User::model()->findAll(
        array(
            'order' => 'user_fname ASC'
         )
    ), 
    'user_id', 'user_fname'
 ),
 array('prompt'=>'Select a name...')
); 
?>
</div>
```